# How can I force the window name of a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, window

I have an internal web system that I want to link to from another internal web system - this is simple, obviously.

The problem is that I want the 2nd system to open links in the users current 'first system window', not open a new window. This again is quite simple, using target='' in the 2nd system.

My question is, how can I always force the 1st system to have a window name of 'abc123' (or whatever)? I don't really want to rework the current log in system to open a new window with this name - I am hoping to be able to force this with a one-liner somehow.

Any ideas?

Matt

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
javascript:document.title="abc123";
```